# No intellisense for extension methods

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, extension-methods, intellisense

I created a extension method, and when I try to call it by **10.getNegative()**, I get no intellisense. But the intellisense works good for

```
int k = 10;
k.getNegative();
```

I was wondering what should be the reason?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)        
    {
        Console.WriteLine(10.getNegative());
    }       
}

static class Math
{
    public static int getNegative(this int i)
    {
        return -i;
    }        
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to delete the .suo file in your project? This will refresh your intellisense.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.aspx it's already a MATH class is there in System library. are namespace are differ ?

Comment: Works for me in Visual Studio 2010. Maybe you need to clean and build your project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you place a dot (.) after an integer, intellisense senses that you may going to write a fractional number; To get the intellisense, use parentheses: `(10).GetNegative()`

Comment: hmm... `Ctrl+Space` is not an option?